# Unable to publish two reports to one Power BI App

Tags: powerbi

I have two reports under one workspace.
[image]

It allows me to add both reports as content to the app.
[image]

However, when I view the APP, I can see the first report only. The second one is not appearing in the app.

[image]

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some basic troubleshooting to identify the issue:

1. Check pane settings to make sure that missing view is indeed set to be visible, not hidden.
2. Make sure you have republished it after adding the second one. By design, Power BI will only update the view after publishing.
3. Also make sure it is not browser cache related issue, by opening it on Incognito Mode or use Ctrl + Shift + R for hard refresh.

Comment: Under Audience, the visibility for the new section was set to invisible. I have changed it to visible and it appears in the app. Thanks.